# How to call a function everytime a view is displayed

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, angular5

I am working on an inappbrowser app. And it has a communication between the webview and the app.

Here is my code :

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController, Platform } from 'ionic-angular';
import { InAppBrowser } from '@ionic-native/in-app-browser';
import { QrcodePage } from '../qrcode/qrcode';
@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
  //template: '<p>Chargement..</p>'
})
export class HomePage {
  ngOnChanges(): void {
    this.onLoad();
  }

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public inAppBrowser: InAppBrowser, public platform: Platform) {
    this.onLoad();
    alert('homepage');
  }

  onLoad(){
    var url = "https://www.myurl.fr/accounts/login?source=mobapp";
    var browser = this.inAppBrowser.create(url,'_blank',{zoom:'no',location:'no',hardwareback:'no'});

      browser.on('loadstart').subscribe((e) => {
        var scriptUrlParam = "window.addEventListener(\"click\",function(e){var href=e.target.getAttribute(\"href\");if(href){location.href=href+\"?source=mobapp\";e.preventDefault();alert(location.href)}});";
        var url = e.url;

        browser.executeScript({code: scriptUrlParam});

        alert(e.url);

        if(url.indexOf("scanner") !== -1){
          this.navCtrl.push(QrcodePage);
          browser.hide();
        }

      });

      browser.show();
  }
}
```

I want the function **onLoad()** to be called everytime I go or return on the view. Because when I use the back button on android, it happens, that is doesn't display the webview anymore..

I have tried some method, but nothing worked like I wanted..

Thanks guys

Comment: ionViewWillLeave() did you try this?

Comment: I did yes, but doesn't call the function when I come back

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
ionViewWillEnter() {
  this.onLoad();
}
```

This will be every time when you view this page.

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-bhynaj?file=pages%2Fhome%2Fhome.ts, please check this

Comment: It works, but I have realized that my problem is that the browser is closed.. So I need to find a way to detect wether or not the browser is closed..

Comment: you can listen  inappbrowser's exit event. 
https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser